# Fragment not showing up on launch

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a bottom navigation bar in my application with two items, and when I select one of them, one fragment shows up and when I select the another one, different fragment shows up. The application works greatly but the only problem is that when I launch the app, neither of the fragments are shown. So what do I have to add so the other one of the fragments is shown upon launch? Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.fields.curiumx.fields;



import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {








private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_explore:
                ExploreFragment exploreFragment = new ExploreFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layoutContainer, exploreFragment).commit();
                return true;


            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                FragmentManager manager1 = getFragmentManager();
                manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layoutContainer, profileFragment).commit();
                return true;



        }return true;



    }
};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);






        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.fields.curiumx.fields.MainActivity">


<FrameLayout


    android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">


</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The two fragments I'm replacing the FrameLayout with can be seen in onNavigationItemSelected method in main activity. I would like that ExploreFragment is shown when the app is launched. Currently the app shows empty FrameLayout on launch.

Comment: When you start the app, add the fragment to the container whose option you want to be selected on launch in the bottom bar.

Comment: It will be good if you will post your answer @Debdeep

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For showing fragments when you launch app ,like you want to launch fragment ExploreFragment  at the time of Starting app put creating fragment code on onCreate. So when app launches it will show ExploreFragment .

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


ExploreFragment exploreFragment = new ExploreFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layoutContainer, exploreFragment).commit();



        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Appreciate your effort to help!

Comment: Glad to hear .Move ahead ,Happy Coding @OlliToivanen